# How do i add a new attribute (column) to each MongoDB document using an existing attribute?

Tags: mongodb, database-design, mongodb-query, database

I want to store two versions of the attribute 'filename' (one will be the regular filename and one will be the lowercase version of filename). I need to store these two attributes so i can do a case-insensitive sort on the returned data. Here is what i have so far:

```
db.collection.update({},{ lowerCaseFileName: filename.toLowerCase() })
```

This is returning the error "filename is not defined". I have been searching for ways to accomplish, however, have not found anything that helpful in solving my problem. I appreciate any help i can get on this, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is [Case Insensitive Indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-case-insensitive/) feature since MongoDB 3.4 :

```
db.collection.createIndex({
    filename: 1
}, {
    collation: {
        locale: 'en',
        strength: 2
    }
})
```

You have to define a `locale` and a `strength` value of 1 or 2 (see [`collation`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/collation/#collation-document-fields)) for case insensitivity

You can then perform insensitive sort with :

```
db.collection.find().collation({
    locale: 'en',
    strength: 2
}).sort({
    filename: -1
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var cursor = db.collection.find({});
cursor.forEach(function(e){
     e.lowercase = e.fileName.toLowerCase();
     db.collection.save(e);
    })
```

Try iterating the collection and update the field